# Prevent post-back when the user presses backspace in Kendo autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Autocomplete dropdown,with contains search filter.

When I select a particular item from the dropdown, the value gets selected and saved to DB successfully but when I press backspace inside the AutoComplete, the page gets post back automatically without the user selecting any of the searched values from the dropdown.

The value after pressing backspace which is not the desired or selected one gets passed to the controller and then to DB.

The implementation is as follows:-

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()

        .Name("SampleCode")
        .DataTextField("Code")


    .Suggest(true)
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetCode", "GetFunct") // call to controller function
                        .Data("FilterCode");
                })
                .ServerFiltering(true);
            })

             .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "selectlist", style = "width:204px" })
             .Events(evt => evt.Close("OnSelectCode"))

)
```

Here is the Javascript Code

```
<script>
    function FilterCode() {

        var SubCode = $("#SubCode")[0].form.SubCode.value;
        //The values in SampleCode dropdown are displayed depending upon the value selected in SubCode dropdown
        return {
            subCode: subCode
        }
    }

    function OnSelectCode(e) {

        var Code = $("#SampleCode").data("kendoAutoComplete").value().toString();
}

</script>
```

The controller functtion works and data is loaded properly in the AutoComplete that's why I haven't posted the corresponding code.

Any idea is most welcome :)

Comment: How come the page is submitted, I do not see any form in here.

Comment: I have not posted the entire .cshtml code,i thought this much would be sufficient.The real problem according to me lies in the one of the scrpit functions or the Kendo Auto Complete implementation.

Comment: @PeturSubev Do you want me to paste the entire code ?

Comment: You mean previous page redirected as user click backspace...not the postback to controller...?

Comment: @Shaz When the user presses backspace and then stops,the page gets post back to controller.
Suppose the Auto Complete shows "Shaz" and if I press backspace twice and then stop,the value "Sh" gets passed to the action in the controller and Db is searched with "Sh" though i never wanted to search "Sh" in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent postback to the controller when user presses back space inside the Kendo Auto complete, you have to make sure to bind the variable with the **close()** function

**Code after the solution:-**

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()

    .Name("SampleCode")
    .DataTextField("Code")


.Suggest(true)
.Filter(FilterType.Contains)
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetCode", "GetFunct") // call to controller function
                    .Data("FilterCode");
            })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
        })

         .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "selectlist", style = "width:204px" })
         .Events(evt => evt.select("OnSelectCode"))  //Changed from "evt.Close" to "evt.Select" to prevent post back when user presses backspace


)
```

You use the .select event with the Kendo Autocomplete control but inside the Javascript function which is "OnSelectCode", you bind the variable using **"close"** property

Change the JavaScript function **OnSelectCode** as follows:-

```
function OnSelectCode(e) {

        var Code = $("#SampleCode").data("kendoAutoComplete").value().toString();
        Code.bind("close", OnSelectCode); // Added to prevent post back when user presses backspace, close the function called by the .select event in Kendo Auto Complete

}
```